# how to remove git diff whitespace and indentation for submodule?

Tags: git, git-submodules

I know how to remove spaces/indentation with git when doing a diff:

```
git diff --color-moved-ws=ignore-space-at-eol,ignore-space-change,ignore-all-space "$@"

git diff --color-moved-ws=allow-indentation-change "$@"

git diff --word-diff=color "$@"
```

I also know how to do a submodule diff:

```
git diff --submodule=diff  "$@"
```

but I'm not able to mix the two solutions.

Adding options in the previous commands does not change the output for the submodules' diff :

```
 git diff --submodule=diff --color-moved-ws=ignore-space-at-eol,ignore-space-change,ignore-all-space "$@"
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: "*What am I doing wrong?*" Most probably nothing. It's either a bug or a misfeature. I suspect `git diff --submodule` runs a different code from `git diff` and doesn't pass it any options.

Answer (score 1):

[phd's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67588714/how-to-remove-git-diff-whitespace-and-indentation-for-submodule#comment119467920_67588714) contains the answer: *you're* not really doing anything *wrong*, it's just that `git submodule` does not support this mode of operation.

Whenever you run into this sort of issue with `git submodule`, consider working around it by:

- doing the submodule operation yourself, and/or
- using `git submodule foreach` to run an arbitrary command in each submodule.

These allow you to get around any submodule bugs.  The former is mostly useful if you know you just want to do something in one particular submodule.  For instance, if the submodule is in `sub/module`, you could run:

```
(cd sub/module; git ...)
```

to run the one given Git command—the `...` part—in the one submodule.

When using `git submodule foreach`, remember that `git submodule` itself sets a few shell variables for you to use: `$sm_path`, `$name`, and so on.  You must protect any reference to these variables from the outer shell, so that the inner shell that `git submodule foreach` runs sees a dollar sign and the name of the variable.  There are multiple ways to do this.  For instance:

```
git submodule foreach 'echo $sm_path'
```

(snipped directly from [the `git submodule` documentation](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-submodule)) does something mildly useful.  You can make a standard shell do the same thing with:

```
git submodule foreach "echo \$sm_path"
```

Here, the double quotes *don't* protect the `$` from interpretation by the outer shell, but the backslash *does*.

(Understanding shell quoting rules can get tricky, but in this particular case, it's simple enough: single quotes quote everything except single quotes; double quotes only quote a few things; and things that are not already quoted can be quoted by using a backslash.)